# How to create custom search box

Tags: android

I am doing search_bar in my android application, for that i created edit text and button. it will search data whatever we edited in edit text.But giving more attraction to my search_bar i have a idea to include android default search box to my application. i am not sure about the possibility of including default search bar to my application. I searched in google, but i cant get any proper guidance. if any of you guys having idea about this issue please guide me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a custom search bar, look at the Dictionary example given in the Android developer guide. I am having trouble myself modifying the example, but it was helpful starting point to create my own customizable search